# Apache RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache-config

I have an encoding problem, using the Apache rewrite rule below:

```
RewriteRule ^/somethingx/somethingy/somethingx_somethingz(.*) /somethingx/somethingy/somethingx_somethingy/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The Rewrite rule works fine but except it is encoding '?' characters in the request as '%3f' characters in the response.

Does anyone know why this is?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try to add [L,QSA,R=301]

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`NE`/`noescape` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags).